# We are trying to change contact owner from trigger

Tags: salesforce

We are trying to update the contact owner depending on a checkbox value.

If the checkbox if true, the user should be allowed to change owner, otherwise the user should try to change owner.

It should update the old owner value only.

```
public void setContactOwner(List <Contact> conList ,Map <id,Contact> oldMap){ 
    system.debug ('newMap '+conList ); 
    system.debug ('inside setcontact function'); 

    List <Contact> newCon = new List<Contact>(); 
    for (Contact con : conList){ 
        system.debug ('Override'+oldMap.get(con.Id).OwnerID__c ); 

        if(con.Override__c == false){ 
            con.OwnerID__c =oldMap.get(con.Id).OwnerID__c ; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What have u try so far? Any Code?

Comment: public void setContactOwner(List <Contact> conList ,Map <id,Contact> oldMap){
   
   system.debug ('newMap '+conList );
   system.debug ('inside setcontact function');
    List <Contact> newCon = new List<Contact>();
   for (Contact con : conList){
   system.debug ('Override'+oldMap.get(con.Id).OwnerID__c );
   
     if(con.Override__c == false){    
       con.OwnerID__c =oldMap.get(con.Id).OwnerID__c ;
       
       }
       
     }
   }

Comment: we are calling this in Before update in trigger

Comment: Issue is resolved